# Как растянуть элементы списка на всю ширину блока?

Tags: html, css

как сделать так чтобы элементы списка растянулись по всей ширине родительского блока. Вот так:[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://s008.radikal.ru/i305/1609/5d/c0dbadfe349c.jpg) Кажется я что-то подобное видел на htmlbook, но он у меня загружается

```css
.parner_img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.parner_conten {
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.parner_conten h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.parner_conten p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
}
.parner_conten ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.parner_conten li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parner_item">
     <div class="parner_img"><img src="http://s012.radikal.ru/i320/1609/a1/397ef046ddeb.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <div class="parner_conten">
      <h2>Елена Анатолиевна</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <ul>
       <li>г. Харьков ( Украина )</li>
       <li>Формат - PREMIUM</li>
       <li>(40 - 200 кв.м.)</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например flex:

```css
.parner_img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.parner_conten {
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.parner_conten h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.parner_conten p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
}
.parner_conten ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  
      display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.parner_conten li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parner_item">
  <div class="parner_img"><img src="http://s012.radikal.ru/i320/1609/a1/397ef046ddeb.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="parner_conten">
    <h2>Елена Анатолиевна</h2>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>г. Харьков ( Украина )</li>
      <li>Формат - PREMIUM</li>
      <li>(40 - 200 кв.м.)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parner_conten ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 0 -250px;
}
.parner_conten li {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```